# iOS - Cancel Update All in App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have turned off automatic download of app updates. I open the App Store and press **Update All**. I realize it's going to take too long or I am on the wrong data connection. I just want to stop the update all command. For now, I don’t see any way to do so. I tried turning off Wi-Fi and data. That stops the download, but leaves all queued apps for the update in an unavailable state.

Is there a way to stop all or is it just racing and press stop on each queued app for update?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no one button way to cancel or stop all the updates started by pressing the "Update All" button, maybe in a future release of iOS we can have a Cancel All or Pause all. [Submit your feeback to Apple, here.](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

**The current solution is to manually stop updating each app that was started updating**:

1. First turn off your data if you are concerned with burning through metered data. [Switch your iOS device into Airplane mode via Control Center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204234)
2. Open the App Store app, switch to the "Updates" tab.
3. Then tap on the download progress circle for each app that is waiting to update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn phone to Airplane Mode
2. Restart the iPhone (Press and quickly release the volume up button. Press and quickly release the volume down button. Press and hold the side button. When the Apple logo appears, release the button).
3. Turn Airplane mode off

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cancel all updates at once. To avoid data usage all you can do is turn off Wifi and mobile data and then cancel the apps one by one.

EDIT: Just had an idea that maybe closing the AppStore app would stop and cancel all updates, but the updates keep running even when the AppStore app is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** mechanism to **cancel all** the running app updates in one go. However, if you are concerned about data, you can individually cancel the app updates. The following instructions apply to iPhone 6s/6s Plus and later (with 3D touch available).

1. Force touch the app icon for which an update is in progress.
2. In the Quick Action menu, you'll find the options to **Cancel** and **Pause** download.

[image]

3. Select the desired option.

[Image Source](http://www.solveyourtech.com/pause-cancel-progress-app-update-iphone-7/)

Comment: You can cancel the updates in the AppStore by tapping on the „progress circle“ which is way faster than looking for all updating apps on multiple home screens and possibly even folders. Your solution would only be useful to *pause* updates as this cannot be done in the AppStore. However, this only makes sense for really large apps if you have slow Wifi and don‘t want to start all over again.

Comment: As noted there is an easier way to do this.  ForceTouch caveat makes this answer no good.